# How do I get a pre-signed url for an API Gateway in Cloudformation using Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I want to make a call to an API Gateway maintained in Cloudformation. I have the Cloudformation stack name (`CF_STACK_NAME`), the API Gateway resource name (`API_GATEWAY_NAME`), and Cloudformation name of the IAM Role I need to assume (`API_ROLE_NAME`).

I can get to my Cloudformation stack via,

```
cf_client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
api_role_resource = cf_client.describe_stack_resource(
       StackName=CF_STACK_NAME,
       LogicalResourceId=API_ROLE_NAME
)
api_resource = cf_client.describe_stack_resource(
       StackName=CF_STACK_NAME,
       LogicalResourceId=API_GATEWAY_NAME
)
```

From reading [Switching to an IAM Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html), I see how to get my keys for the role,

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
credentials = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/{role_name}'.format(
        account_id=sts_client.get_caller_identity().get('Account'),
        role_name=api_role_resource['PhysicalResourceId']
    ),
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)['Credentials']
```

But when I want to call the API url,

```
apigateway_client     = boto3.client('apigateway')
restapi_id = apigateway_client.get_rest_api(restApiId=api_logical_id)['id']
url = f'https://{restapi_id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage}/{api_query}

api_output = requests.get(url).json()
```

I get,

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetRestApi operation: User: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:user/my-user is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2::/restapis/ServerlessRestApi
```

How do I make my API call using this CloudFormation info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are not using the new credentials from STS.

You will need to create the apigateway client using the new credentials using code like this:

```
client = boto3.client(
       'apigateway',
        aws_access_key_id=credentials['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
```

Comment: And to actually make the API call, will this client generate a signed URL?

Comment: @aidan. I don't understand your question.

Comment: So I think you answered part of my problem. I am looking to call the api like `url = f'https://{restapi_id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage}/{api_query}`, but I believe I need credentials to make the call. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: The answer depends on how you configured API gateway. Do you plan to call apigateway from a web browser or from the boto3 client APIs? I would redo your question to be clearer on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Nevermind. The problem is on my side now and is beyond the scope of this question. We need to fix some policies.